# How to get access to entity by his name?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I've got two projects based on single database. In the first project I've got every entities classes (with annotations like @Entity) but in second I don't have it and I can't use it. But I need to make an CRUD operations based on this entities.

So, how to use this entities based only on tables names?

I try like this:

```
this.entityManger.getRepository('user')
```

but it throw me this:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "user" was found.
```

my TypeORMConfig looks like this:

```
            type: 'postgres',
            url: this.dbURL(),
            migrationsTransactionMode: 'each',
            migrationsRun: true,
            synchronize: true,
            keepConnectionAlive: true,
```

can someone tell me how to connect to entity by only his name?

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure `nest` supports such a thing out of the box, but you can surly use the underlying `TypeORM` to do so:

```js
import {getRepository} from "typeorm";

// later in your code
const userRepo = getRepository('users'); // assuming your table name is indeed 'users'
```

with the repo object you can do whatever you want as it is a `TypeORM` repository.

note that the type on this example is `unknown` so every object that comes from it will be of `unknown` type.
you can simply supply it with a type of your choice (or interface or simply `any`) to avoid further typing issues.